# Pass file from file() to Perl program PHP

Tags: perl, localhost, easyphp

I have a PHP code that stores contents of a url by file() method like

```
$contents=file("http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/2AID.pdb");
```

I need to pass these $contents to a perl program by shell_exec() method , something like following

```
$result=shell_exec("perl_prog.pl $contents");
```

My question is how to pass this $contents to Perl program. I tried like following

```
@file=<@ARGV>;
```

but its not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That shell_exec() code is utterly vulnerable to shell injection - you're trusting that the remote service won't include something like:

```
; rm -rf /
```

As well, `file()` returns the file contents as an array - you can't pass arrays over the command line directly. Only strings.

A moderately safer version is:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://etc....');
$safe_contents = escapeshellarg($contents);
$result = shell_exec('perl_prog.pl $safe_contents');
```

On the Perl side, you'd use

```
my ($contents) = @ARGV;
```

Comment: According to the docs, [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) already adds quotes. Fixed.